# Order by as Number, even if column type is string, Laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-7

I have a string column, but I have only double numbers (age), and I want to do a order by, but the obvious problem is that i get wrong response, because is string. ex: (1,10,2,3,4,40,etc...). In my code $table = name of the table, sort_by, in this particular case is "age".

```
$query->orderBy("CAST(" . $table . $request->sort_by . "as NUMERIC)", 'ASC');
```

Error:

> Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table
>   "CAST(people"↵LINE 1:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `orderByRaw` and cast the text number to an integer:

```
$query->orderByRaw("age::int")
```

Note that if you have a persistent need to use this text number column as actual numeric data, it might imply a design problem, and perhaps the column should really be integer in your Postgres table.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's in production for some time.  I tried "  $query->orderByRaw('people.age::double', $direction);  "  //int, float , and I get "parameter was not defined"

Comment: This is not what my answer suggests, and `orderByRaw` takes a _single_ raw string input.  Please try using my actual answer.

Comment: I tried exact code, and I get an error, because I also have float values, and I replace "int" with "float", and works. Thank you!

Comment: OK...it really sounds like that column should be some numeric type.  Maybe make that change if you have a long term need for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Since i was using Mongodb and elqouent ORM, this works fine for me

```
$query->orderBy("age::int")
```